# Security of virtualbox

Tags: security, virtualbox

I have windows xp installed in virtualbox (running on linux) that has the grdp remote display enabled. Is it possible, if one was to connect to my virtualmachine through rdp, to hack into my computer. I know that the network is shared and that it is assigned a local ip and that shared folders (which i have disabled) exist. I was just wondering if the memory of my host computer can be seen from the virtual machine or is it completely sandboxed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory the Windows XP VM should be completely sandboxed.

But it is possible that either VirtualBox or your CPU (if you use hardware virtualization) has a bug that can lead to a security breach of your host.